# Expanding searchbar whose icon changes functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a searchbar with an input area that expands outward to the left of its search icon button when that button is clicked (the icons I am using are Font Awesome icons). As the input area expands, I want the icons to the left to be pushed to the left with it.

When the input area contains user input to be searched, I want the function of that same search icon button to change so that the next time the button is clicked, it acts as a submit button instead of a button for expanding/retracting the input area.

I very nearly have a working version of the code. It just has a few kinks to be worked out that elude me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="icon-bar">
    <span class="searchbox-container">
        <form class="searchbox">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search"     class="searchbox-input">
            <button class="searchbox-button"><i id="search-icon" class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/** Icon bar **/
#icon-bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #323232;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.375em /* 6px */;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
    -o-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
/** Icon **/
.icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/** Searchbar **/
.searchbox-container{
    width:200px;
}
.searchbox{
    position:relative;
    min-width:50px;
    width:0%;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden; 
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}
.searchbox-input{
    top:0;
    right:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    background: transparent;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 55px 0px 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    color: #323232;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
.searchbox-button{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    font-size:20px;
    right: 0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#323232;
    background:transparent;
}
.searchbox-open{
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
function clickSearchIcon() {
    // If searchbox-input has input...
    if ($.trim($('.searchbox-input').val()).length !== 0) {
        // Upon clicking searchbox-button
        $("searchbox-button").attr('type','submit');
    }
    // If searchbox-input is empty...
    else {
        // Upon clicking searchbox-button...
        $('.searchbox-button').click(function(){
            // If searchbox is open...
            if ($('.searchbox').hasClass('searchbox-open')){
                // Close searchbox,
                $('.searchbox').removeClass('searchbox-open');
                // Defocus input area
                $('.searchbox-input').focusout();
            }
            // If searchbox is closed...
            else {
                // Open searchbox,
                $('.searchbox').addClass('searchbox-open');
                // Focus input area
                $('.searchbox-input').focus();      
            }
        })
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    clickSearchIcon()
});
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/christophercostello/pen/pPbVjE)

Any insight and help would be appreciated!